# Getting directory of file being executed

Tags: c#

Is there a command in c# that receives the directory of the aspx.cs file currently being run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) Method

It gets the current working directory of the application.

Comment: Actually I recently had a problem with this approach, when opening an application from a file-associated document from the desktop. Use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location is more save.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`